# Handle two events on button click

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am a bit new to the asp.net/jQuery game, and I seem to be having difficulty. I am using colorbox to make a modal window popup, and I want an upload picture form on that modal window. I have a button to open up the add photo form:

```
<a href="#" class="addpicture">Add/Edit picture(s)</a><br />
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".addpicture").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#page1" });
        });
 </script>
```

Thus far my modal window is working perfectly, and is displaying the following upload form and next button:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="picup" runat="server" class="upload" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" type="button" runat="server" Text="Next Page" class="nextpage" />
```

Here's where I am stuck; I am trying to have the next button upload the picture, and move to a second modal window, which I am going to implement a crop function on. The problem is, to do this, I need a jquery event handler:

```
$(".nextpage").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#page2" });
```

I also need a serverside event handler to do the actual upload:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        picup.PostedFile.SaveAs("\Pictures\1-a.jpg")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Upload Failed")
    End Try
End Sub
```

However, when I put in a breakpoint, this event handler is never firing. 
A possible solution I thought up is to make a hidden button that fires the javascript, and click that button from vb, but I couldn't figure out how to click a button from vb. Is there something I'm doing fundamentally wrong? Is there a good way to accomplish what I want?

Edit: I have changed the way I am doing this, instead of multiple modal windows, I am loading a separate page in an iframe on the modal window, then I can have a postback without reloading the main page. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files with the fileUpload control you need a postback, otherwise the event will never fire.

- There are a couple of plugins por jQuery that promise to enable uploading via ajax but i've never tried any.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method lets you attach different behaviors to an element :

Example:

```
$("#a").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(e){
     $(this).text($(this).text() + " event triggered " );
});
```

Comment: But does this bind() method allow one of the events to be a server-side event? It does not appear like it does